# MongoDB aggregate objects with an array of objects?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here is a part of my collection in `json`:

```
[{"company":"Lenovo", "models": 
    [{"model":"ThinkPad T400", "gens": 
        [{"gen":"3", "start":2012},
        {"gen":"2", "start":2008},
        {"gen":"1", "start":2004}]
    }...]
}...]
```

I am trying to come-up with an aggregate command that will return me the following:

```
[{ "_id":"Lenovo", 
  "models":[{ "model": "ThinkPad T400", 
              "gens":["1","2","3"]
            }...]
}...]
```

I have tried the following aggregate command but it didn't work:

```
db.makes.aggregate([{
    $group:{
        _id: '$company',
        models: { $push:  { 
            model: "$models.model", 
            gen: "$models.gens.gen"
        }} 
    } 
}])
```

I get this result:

```
[{ "_id":"Lenovo", 
  "models":[{ "model": ["ThinkPad T400"], 
              "gens":[ ["1","2","3"] ]
            }...]
}...]
```

It is probably because each my object has an array of objects (Models) and that objects have an array of objects too (Gens).

**What is the right request to the MongoDB that would return me my expected result?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be missing something here, but it seems to me that your original data is very similar to what you want to get. Is there more than one document that has `company` set to `Lenovo`?

If there isn't you could get almost what you are looking for with a much simpler command:

```
db.makes.find({}, {_id: 0, company: 1, "models.model": 1, "models.gens.gen": 1 });
```

It wouldn't be exactly the result you are looking for:

```
{
  "company": "Lenovo",
  "models": [
    {
      "model": "ThinkPad T400",
      "gens": [
        {
          "gen": 3
        },
        {
          "gen": 2
        },
        {
          "gen": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And it would only work if the `company` field is unique already, but it would be way easier for MongoDB to provide since you wouldn't have to use the Aggregation Framework and you wouldn't need to unwind any potentially long arrays.

Answer (score 8):

Try this query:

```
db.makes.aggregate([
{$unwind : '$models'},
{
    $group:{
        _id: '$company',
        models: { $push:  { 
            model: "$models.model", 
            gen: "$models.gens.gen"
        }} 
    }
}])
```

the output will be

```
{
    "_id" : "Lenovo",
    "models" : [ 
        {
            "model" : "ThinkPad T400",
            "gen" : [ 
                "3", 
                "2", 
                "1"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **$unwind** operator to pop out and access the object

My data is

[image]

My Query is when i do aggregation

```
[{$unwind : '$geolocation'},
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: {city:"$geolocation.city",year: { $year: "$geolocation.date" }},
           count: { $sum: 1 }
         }
     }
   ]
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "city" : "Bengaluru",
        "year" : 2020
    },
    "count" : 3.0
}
```